# FullCalendar - returning to selected month after posting

Tags: json, fullcalendar

We are using a modal for the input fields and a separate screen to handle the posting of the data to the database.  When a user selects a date a few months away and posts, they are redirected to the current month.  It would be nice to keep them on the same month they just entered an event.

For example, today is December 4.  I click to February 2016, enter an event, and on refresh, the calendar is loaded back to December.

I would like the calendar to remain on February.

Any ideas for me? THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [defaultDate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) in fullcalendar to control the initial view - setting it to the start date of the last entered event, example Feb. 13 2016

http://jsfiddle.net/zLLL3s1z/1/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  /* set this somehow - either in the redirect page logic/controller, or yank from url with javascript */
  defaultDate: '2016-02-13'
});
```

Comment: APOLOGIES: I CAN'T FIGURE OUT THE FORMATTING - Thanks, but that didn't work.


`var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

         defaultDate: '2016-02-13',

         <% if (view == "D"){ %>
          defaultView: 'agendaDay',
         <% } else if (view == "W") { %>
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
         <% } else { %>
          defaultView: 'month',
         <% } %>

          header: {
            left: 'today',
            center: 'prev title next',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          selectable: true,
`

Comment: I see why it fails though, I am pulling the data dynamically only for the current month, so I need to pass those parameters to the events.asp page as well.

Comment: You'd need to pass the parameter of "lastStartDate" or something and use the start date of the recently entered event, then it'd be along the lines of  .fullCalendar({ defaultDate: <% lastStartDate %>  // I don't know ASP, sorry about syntax

Comment: that's the trouble, it's completely ignoring the defaultDate attribute - even when hard coded.

Comment: HEAD BONK.  I needed to update the fullcalendar.js file.  My version didn't have the defaultDate command in it.  BONK BONK BONK

Comment: Ah, yeah I think that was added in version 2.xx. Got it working?